# UTF-8 characters in an email form

Tags: forms, utf-8, character-encoding

The below code should result in a UTF-8 encoded email via a contact form that sends data to the relevant database table. However, it's still not showing UTF-8 characters correctly. Can you see if I've mis-typed/not added/messed up with the code below? Many thanks!

```
<?php
$text = "Results from form:\n\n";
$space = ' ';
$line = '
';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
if ($req == '1')
{
if ($value == '')
{echo "$key is empty";die;}
}
$j = strlen($key);
if ($j >= 20)
{echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 20 characters";die;}
$j = 20 - $j;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++)
{$space .= ' ';}
$value = str_replace('\n', "$line", $value);
$conc = "{$key}:$space{$value}$line";
$text .= $conc;
$space = ' ';
}
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$emailadd.'');
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh charset=utf-8 CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the rapid response Chris - on second thoughts, however, our email form relies on a 'func.php' file with various settings for the site included. Currently the 'sendemail' code is as follows:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$hostmail." \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To : ".$hostmail." \r\n";
return mail($to, $subj, $body, $headers);
```

I've tried altering is as follows, without success... any ideas?

```
$headers .= "From: ".$hostmail." \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To : ".$hostmail." \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$body=htmlspecialchars_decode($body,ENT_QUOTES);
return mail($to, "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subj)."?=",$body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 4):

This may or may not be useful, but I think I appreciate your pain when it comes to handling mailing errors in PHP, so I thought I'd at least try help get this thread going!

One thing I didn want to ask was are you sure that the values being posted coming in in UTF-8 encoding? Also, I can't help but think the new-line characters might be causing some funky behaviour, so why not try something like this instead (where applicable):

```
line = "\r\n";
$value = str_replace('\n', $line, $value);
```

Notice the **double quotes** around the new-line character I put in for $line...I'm assuming that the first '\n' above is physically being put into the value and needs replacing? Otherwise, especially with plain-text e-mail, you shouldn't have to worry about parsing for those new-line characters, just feed it straight through to the mail message.

***EDIT:***

Not sure if this will help, but after running the most basic mail send functions using [Zend's mail libraries](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) - UTF-8 and base64 encoding - and inspecting the source of the message that came through, this is basically all you need for your plain-text mail, given this as the message:

```
$message = "This is a\r\ntest message";
```

...the mail source snippet will be:

```
Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2011 16:24:16 +0300
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0

VGhpcyBpcyBhDQp0ZXN0IG1lc3NhZ2U=
```

***EDIT #2:***

Ok, I think I've finally figured out something that will help, although this will only help when sending **HTML** mail messages with Czech special characters. The problem doesn't seem to be as much to do with the character encoding as the HTML special characters (well, for me anyways!), so the following code seemed to yield the original text just fine in my trusty Firefox web browser:

```
<?php

// original message...
$message = "To je nějaký ukázkový text.\r\nTento text je na dalším řádku.";

// convert as many characters as possible in PHP < 5.4...
$message = htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

// I suspect this next line will work for all characters in PHP >= 5.4...
// $message = htmlentities($message, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');

// if not all characters are being converted, plug the missing ones in here
// with their relevant codes...
$missing_characters = array
(
    'ě' => '&#283',
    'ř' => '&#345;'
);

// heavy function, but I wasn't trying to be efficient ;)
foreach ($missing_characters as $char => $code)
    $message = str_replace($char, $code, $message);

// this should give you the original string in a browser...
echo $message;

?>
```

***EDIT #3:***

And finally, to achieve the same result with text visible in **plain-text** mail messages is a lot simpler. Just base64 encode the message, set the appropriate headers, and use [PHP's mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to do the rest. Here's how I got it working:

```
// original message...
$message = "To je nějaký ukázkový text.\r\nTento text je na dalším řádku.";
$message = base64_encode($message);

// headers...
$headers = "";
$headers .= "From: your-email@domain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0";

mail("destination-email@domain.com", "Subject Here", $message, $headers);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response Chris - on second thoughts, however, our email form relies on a 'func.php' file with various settings for the site included. Currently the 'sendemail' code is as shown in the edit above...

Comment: To be honest, the headers look good, and apart from being pedantic about which order they go in - like putting the MIME header first - I can't really fault them :) Maybe I should actually ask what problem exactly are you experiencing? Inserting rows into the database incorrectly? Receiving strange-looking mail on the other side? I hope we're onto the right track here :)

Comment: There's a contact form which posts data to 'sendmail.php' (the code of sendmail.php is in the original post). Then that should send me an email with encoded characters... but it doesn't. Everything I can see is correctly encoded as UTF-8 but there must be something I've missed!

Comment: Thanks for the comment JoeW, and for your patience, I feel like we're making progress! So you don't receive the e-mail at all, or are you receiving the mail, but the content is not base64 encoded? Also, have you thought of using [Zend's mailing libraries](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) to get rid of some of the headaches caused by the more mundain operations, or is that not an option for you?

Comment: We have two versions of the site - one in English, one in Czech. All use the same func.php and both send emails without a problem... except for UTF-8 encoded characters (Czech uses some other characters in its standard alphabet).

Comment: Just edited my answer, not sure if you've had a chance to see it yet...I also forgot to ask if the html pages on the site are encoded using UTF-8? If they're not posting UTF-8 encoded characters then that might also be the problem...hope this is helping! :)

Comment: Thanks Chris - yes, you're providing very helpful food for thought! All pages are encoded in UTF-8, including the English ones should any users use the wrong form etc. Perhaps you could amend my code above and add it to your original reply? My head is ticking very slowly now after working on this for ages!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4469/discussion-between-chris-kempen-and-joew)

Comment: Are you aware there is a mb_send_mail() in PHP?  Im not saying you should definitely be using it, but its worth looking at

Comment: I'm starting to get that feeling of mis-placed help again ;) Quite right carpii, thank you for the assistance, definitely worth looking at JoeW...